# How to Send SMS from angular App to mobile

Tags: typescript, angular6, node-modules, sms-gateway, ngxs

I want to send SMS from Angular6 web application. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Please suggest me some reference link or code sample.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) and a firebase function. You wouldn't want to send the message from the app due to security concerns. You need to keep your api and auth token secret. Just create a serverless function somewhere that uses Twilio and you're all set!